# Will this be considered a pure reducer function in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, pure-function

I have this reducer function and I am incrementing the value of voteScore by 1 inside it. Is this the right way to do it without breaking the constraint that reducer function should be pure function?

```
function comment (state = {}, action) {
 ...
 switch(action.type) {
 ...
  case UP_VOTE_COMMENT:
   const upVoteScore = parseInt(state[id]['voteScore'], 10) + 1

   return {
    ...state,
    [id]: {
     ...state[id],
     voteScore: upVoteScore
    }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: It is a pure function because it has no side effects.  However, parse and increment logic might be better off in an action.

Comment: Does it satisfy the definition of *pure*?  Does it always produce the same output given the same input, and have no side effects?

Comment: Also, I have to sort the comments based on the vote score. Will sort inside one of the cases in the reducer be still ok?

Comment: @DavinTryon Isn't action (I am using action-creator) just supposed to return the object with **type** property?

Comment: @DavinTryon, limitlessriver That's a matter of style. Neither way is right and neither is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The idea of a pure function is that it always produces the same output based on the input.

The current `voteScore` is part of the "input" in the parameters.